# Sorting without using divide and conquer algos in less than n*n time

Tags: data-structures

Consider the following input :
                    8,4,15,9,32,44,55

Propose an algorithm to sort these in ascending order in less than n*n time complexity.
  Without using any divide and conquer approach

Comment: Propose that you do your own homework.

Comment: Is this homework? If so tag it appropriately.

Comment: Why would one not divide and conquer?

Answer (score 1):

For relatively small integers such as these you can use [bucket sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort) or [radix sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort), it will be `O(n)`, and is not devide and conquer.

For larger ints it is still possible, but bucket sort will consume too much space, and radix sort will be `O(n*d)`, where d is the number of digits in the biggest number.